# Modifying HTML form while getting new code from php

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to make an red error warning signal but instead of modifying the current input box, it creates another.

Can you help me?

```
.error form input[type="text"]{
    box-shadow: 0 0 1em red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1em red;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 1em red;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1em red;
}

.error3 input[type="password"]{
    box-shadow: 0 0 1em red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1em red;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 1em red;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1em red;
}
```

PHP

```
$errors = array(); 
if (empty($Username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }


if ($Password_1 != $Password_2) {
    array_push($errors, "<div class='error3'>Password isn't the same.</div>");
}
```

HTML (a part of it, there's more inputs form email, username etc)

```
<?php include('includes/errors.php'); ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Password_2">Verify password</label>
    <div class="input-icon">
        <i class="mdi mdi-lock"></i>
        <span class="passtoggle mdi mdi-eye toggle-password"></span>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="Password_2" placeholder="Verify password" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to modify the code, didn't work. The error3 divclass closes too fast.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I added in the PHP section only this

```
        if ($Password_1 != $Password_2) {
            array_push($errors, "

            <style>
            .form-group input[type='password']{
    box-shadow: 0 0 1em red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1em red;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 1em red;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1em red;
}</style>



            Not the same password.");
        }
```